# Minimal licence needed to pause/resume virtual machine via vSphere CLI

Tags: vmware-vsphere, licensing

I manage VMware ESXi 4.0 server running mix of Windows virtual machines. I've installed VMware vSphere CLI in hope to pause/resume virtual machine and copy its image to NFS datastore. I've got CLI up and running, I can list datastores, registered machines, configuration and etc, but when i try to start machine with:

`vmware-cmd --config /etc/vmware-vcli/esxi.conf /vmfs/volumes/_insane_uuid_/tester/tester.vmx start`

it gives me this error:

```
Operation cannot be performed. 

SOAP Fault:
-----------
Fault string: fault.RestrictedVersion.summary
Fault detail: RestrictedVersionFault
```

From brief googling this looks like problem with unsufficient licence level. Current licence is:

`ESXi 4 Single Server Licensed for 1 physical CPUs (1-6 cores per CPU)`

And my question is: what licence should I purchase in order to make CLI work? There won't be any change in number of CPUs, memory size or number of physical servers whatsoever.

Thanks for answer in advance.
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESXi 5.0 no longer has these restrictions; it is essentially the full version of ESX.